# C# UWP Add custom controls to start menu tile

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp, windows-10

Can I add custom (clickable) controls to the start menu tile of my application? I only know about text, images and badges, but I would like to draw on the tile and handle click events myself.

Is that in theory possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to create interactive tiles in Windows 10. All you can do is to create [Live Tiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-badges-notifications) and [Secondary tiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465398.aspx).

Comment: Do you think it's possible to cheat the system by adding controls to the tile window using dll calls?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using any method. Live tiles are made just to show informations..

Answer (score 0):

Since the 1511 update you can add jump lists to your tile; that doens't make the content of your live tile clickable but can give your tile via the context menu additional options; see http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/uwp/developing-for-windows-10-implementing-jump-lists/ for a good howto

Comment: But they are desktop-only.